# Regex to escape special character and match word in a string

Tags: regex

I have a paragraph which contains i++ and ++i:

```
para = "This is what i++ is do ++i and in i I dim ++ +"
```

and I want to find all occurrences of i++ and ++i. As I am a total beginner at this so this is what I write at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

```
[i+]
```

This works fine but as you can see it also gives me all the `I i + ++` everywhere in the string so I added this `\b[i+]\b` but it doesn't select the + sign attached with i++ . Also, it selects the single i in the string. Which means it is not treating i++ or ++i as a single string.

How can I change my regex to select i++ or ++i in the string

Comment: What is the language or tool? Simply do `\+\+i|i\+\+`

Comment: ok.I am not looking for any specific language. But this `\+\+i|i\+\+`  worked

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your `+` signs.

You can use the RegEx [`i\+\+|\+\+i`](https://regex101.com/r/nNeYec/1)

- `i\+\+` matches `i++` literally
- `\+\+i` matches `++i` literally

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/nNeYec/1)

Comment: OP doesn't need to escape `+` in his / her own regex.

Comment: @revo Whether `+` on its own needs to be escaped depends on the regex syntax in use. The OP hasn't specified, but is using regex101.com, in which case `+` is a metacharacter and does require `+` to be escaped to be taken literally.

Comment: @hvd Please let me know which regex flavor treats `+` as a special character in a character class.

Comment: `\+\+i|i\+\+` and `i\+\+|\+\+i` both worked . Can you tell me what is the difference

Comment: @revo Is that relevant? The first thing the OP needs to do is get rid of the character class.

Comment: @RaghavPatnecha There is none, `|` only means `OR`. The order doesn't matter.

Comment: @hvd It's relevant since it was the subject of my first comment which you criticized.

Comment: @revo Okay. In that case, let me respond to your first comment again: is that relevant? The fact that the OP doesn't need to escape `+` in a character class doesn't change the fact that the OP does need to escape `+` outside of a character class, and in this answer, `+` is no longer in a character class.

Comment: @hvd Do not mix-up over different points, please. This answer says *You need to escape your `+` signs.*, no, OP doesn't need to escape his / her `+` signs unless they use this solution. That sentence doesn't apply simply.

Comment: @revo I guess I'm giving both Zenoo and the OP the benefit of the doubt, that the only reason that the OP used `[i+]` in the first place was because `i+` wasn't matching any `+` characters. Under that assumption, this answer is correct. But if that assumption is incorrect, yes, your point is valid.

Comment: @revo Looking at OP's example and him explicitly saying `I want to find all occurrences of i++ and ++i `, I think we can safely assume the answer is indeed matching OP's needs.

Comment: @Zenoo Solution is correct (I commented it too under question) but first statement is not. It's a matter of rephrasing.